# Quantum superposition follows from energy conservation? (possibly not a crackpot question. It's just an area of research in the fundamentals)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, superposition

This question is inspired by research in [resource theories of coherence](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10943), research in [quantum thermodynamics and its connection to coherence](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.7740), and section 10.1 (The Adiabatic Theorem) in Griffiths. The answer might actually be in one of the papers I linked to, but I dot not understand them very well.

Suppose we have a particle in the ground state of an infinite square well with length $L$. Consider then the following two scenarios:

1. We expand the well infinitely quickly to length $2L$. The (expectation value of the) energy of the particle is conserved -- no energy leaks outside the well. The particle is now in a superposition of the eigenstates of the new well.
2. We expand the well extremely slowly (adiabatically) to length $2L$. The energy of the particle is not conserved -- it is removed by the particle's interaction with the moving wall during the expansion. After the expansion, the particle is in the ground state of the new well. It is not in a superposition of the eigenstates of the new well.

From the above two scenarios, is it correct to infer a strong connection between energy and superposition? Is the particle's ability to exist in a superposition extracted with the extracted energy in the case of slow expansion? Is the resource in [resource theories of superposition](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10943) nothing more than energy itself?

Comment: How does energy leak out of an infinite well?

Comment: Superposition is a result of linearity.

Comment: @probably_someone We assume that during the expansion the particle can lose some of its kinetic energy pushing the wall -- like a classical ball in a chamber with a piston.

Comment: So you're saying that scenario 1 involves an external force and 2 doesn't?

Comment: They both involve an external force, but in the second scenario the particle has to time to "realise" that the wall is expaning and interact with it while it expands. If you imagine a classical ball, then in scenario 1 the particle does not have time to bounce off the expanding wall and lose energy to it. While in scenario 2 it does.

Comment: Scenario 2 is an adiabatic expansion. Like in classical thermodynamics, energy does not stay constant inside the container (infinite well, or piston chamber).

Comment: In D. J. Griffiths' "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics" textbook on page 370 of the second edition, he says "...if the well expands suddenly, the resulting state is still \psi^i(x) (Figure 10.2(c)), which is a complicated linear combination of the eigenstates of the new Hamiltonian (Problem 2.38). In this case energy is conserved (at least, its expectation value is); as in the free expansion of a gas (into a vacuum) when the barrier is suddenly removed, no work is done."

Comment: The questions seems to be a little vague. If you take a particle in any superposition and let it lose energy, it will go to the ground state. Does this imply a connection between the two? I don't know. What kind of connection? Can you be more precise?

Comment: Ok here's how I first started thinking about it. Take a particle in the ground state of an infinite well. Expand the well suddenly (total energy in the well does not change), and you get superposition. Is the reason you got superposition that god went "I can't let the particle be in an energy eigenstate of the new well. The energy of the particle does not match any of the energy eigenstates. It must be in a superposition or energy conservation will be broken, and I can't let that happen."

Comment: One more thought: let's say that new well is such that its first energy level has the same energy as the ground level of the old well. Although energy conservation would not be violated if the particle were to be in the first level of the new well, it does not (because the shape of the wavefunction right after this sudden expansion does not fit the shape of the wavefunction of the first excited state of the new well). So there can exist superposition even if energy conservation will not be violated.

Comment: At this point I might -- and probably should -- say "Ok nevermind, clearly superposition does not follow directly from energy conservation." However, I feel like I should think about this a little longer. I will go plot the wavefunction after expansion and make sure it does not settle to be the first excited state of the new well. If it doesn't, then I will let go.

Comment: The whole point of resource theories of coherence and superposition is that the existing resource theories (including, in particular, energy) are insufficient.

Answer (score -1):

Take a particle in the ground state of an infinite well. Expand the well suddenly (total energy in the well does not change), and you get superposition. Is the reason you got superposition that god went "I can't let the particle be in an energy eigenstate of the new well. The energy of the particle does not match any of the energy eigenstates. It must be in a superposition or energy conservation will be broken, and I can't let that happen."

Most likely not. Here is why: let's say that new well is such that its first energy level has the same energy as the ground level of the old well -- so the new well has width $2L$. Although energy conservation would not be violated if the particle were to be in the first level of the new well, it does not (because the shape of the wavefunction right after this sudden expansion does not fit the shape of the wavefunction of the first excited state of the new well). So there can exist superposition even if energy conservation will not be violated.

Here is a short animation of a how the probability density ($|\Psi|^2$) evolves right after expansion. I set $L=1e-18 m$, and $\hbar = 1$. Also I only sum up to the first 200 eigenstates of the new well. Note how it does not evolve to be in the first excited eigenstate of the new well. You can see that also from the decomposition of the wavefunction after expansion into the eigenstates of the new well, and noticing that time evolution does not collapse it into one eigenstate.

[image]